# Windows batch merge multiple text files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've been looking for a solution to my problem, but couldn't find an answer. I'm desperate.

I need to create a script, which concatenates multiple text files into one. my files in folder like this

```
- aaaa.txt
- aaaa (1).txt
- aaaa (2).txt
- aaaa (3).txt
- bbb.txt
- bbb (1).txt
- bbb (2).txt
- bbb (3).txt
```

i want merge file like this

```
- aaaa.txt
- bbb.txt
```

i have tried like this

```
@echo off
for /r "." %%a in (*.txt) do (
   echo %%~na
   type %%a >> %%~na.txt
)
```

but merge file is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following setting for the source directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"

FOR %%b IN ("%sourcedir%\*(*).txt") DO (
 for /f "delims=(" %%e in ("%%~nb") do (
  set "destfilename=%%e"
  if "!destfilename:~-1!"==" " (
   type "%%b">>"%sourcedir%\!destfilename:~0,-1!.txt"
  ) else (
   type "%%b">>"%sourcedir%\%%e.txt"
  )
  ECHO del "%%b"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Process a list of filenames matching the `*(*.txt`  mask.

Derive the base name by re-processing the name part, tokenising on `(`.

Append the file found to the basename.txt; If the last character of the base name is <kbd>Space</kbd>, then remove that terminal space so the destination will not be "basename<kbd>Space</kbd>.txt".

The `del` is merely `echo`ed, to be enabled by removing the `echo`  if desired after testing.

Note this does not perform recursion as implied by the original code, and also processes files named `basename(?).txt` as well as `basename(?) .txt`- and the basename may not contain <kbd>(</kbd>